# React-js error undefined "type" property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to logout the user immediately after login , so I could see in redux if It works and I get this error: *Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?*

I should get AUTH_LOGOUT action in my redux after the success- [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNXb.png).
As I understand the error Is in the checkAuthTimeout:

```
export const checkAuthTimeout = (expirationTime) => {
return dispatch => {    
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(logout())
    }, expirationTime )
}}
```

My logout:

```
export const logout = () => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT
}}
```

And auth:

```
export const auth = (email, password) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    const authData = {
        email:email,
        password:password,
        returnSecureToken: true
    }
    axios.post('https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=AIzaSyCpqBy-KjAJWCMUYLHVWAIu_HWZd3yzHVE', authData)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(authSuccess(response.data.idToken, response.data.localId));
            dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(response.data.expiresIn));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(authFail(err.response.data.error));
        });
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Redux Devtools to inspect which actions are dispatching? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is pretty clear, your action type has value of undefined. Meaning actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT is undefined.

Try do a console.log on actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT, probably it's not defined or not imported properly. Show us the file where it is defined and imported, but I am positive the problem is either on how you exported or imported it.

Comment: Thanks , I've made a stupid spelling mistake at actionTypes : export const AUTH_LOGUT = 'AUTH_LOGOUT' ...